# The identity ID is returned but not recorded in the table

Tags: zend-framework, sql-insert, zend-db, last-insert-id

I am building a project in Zand 1.1.

I created 'email' table and I want to enter record with the insert method. My code looks like:

```php
$this->_db_table = new Mconsole_Model_DbTable_Emailmessages(array(
   'db' => parent::getDb()
));
$this->_db_table->insert('email',data);
```

This code return last inserted id(for example '17') but no realy record inserted in the table. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you provide more code or details? What is $this->_db_table an instance of? Are you running this inside of a transaction and forgetting to commit?

Comment: thank you dear. yes. thats my problem.